# Function REGEXEXTRACT parameter 2 value error

Tags: regex, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm trying to extract all the text between 2 words in a cell full of text, in Google Sheets and can't find something that works with Regextract ... everything returns an error

I have tried :

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(B2,"Word1(.*)Word2")
```

any other suggestions ?

The only formula that works it's a long formula FIND

```
=TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(B2,"Word1","|",1),FIND("|",SUBSTITUTE(B2,"Word1","|",1))+1,FIND("Word2",SUBSTITUTE(B2,"Word1","|",1))-FIND("|",SUBSTITUTE(B2,"Word1","|",1))-1))
```

The text inside the cell has also carriage returns ...does it matter ?

Thank you.

Comment: That looks like it should work according to the [documentation](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098244?hl=en). Is it really `Word1` and `Word2` in the regexp? If not, show the actual regular expression, you may have some special characters that have to be escaped.

Comment: Instead of Word1 and Word2 I'm using some localized words based on the content , nothing special in them ... just simple letters ... but it doesn't work ... I've updated the info above with the formula that works ... maybe it can help you

Comment: Didn't you see how I fixed the code markdown in your question the first time? Why couldn't you do that yourself when you added additional code, instead of me having to fix it again?

Comment: The error message clearly says there's smoething wrong with the regexp, so it's probably not as simple as you claim. Post the actual code.

Comment: Why do you need all the substitutions, instead of just `FIND("Word1", B2)` and `FIND("Word2", B2)`?

Comment: @Barmar I've discovered the problem while testing with something simple ... Word2 is on another row inside the cell like when you hit Command + ENTER so it's after a carriage return ... does regex still works in this case ? ...if so, how can I make it work ? and please also tell me how can I escape any special characters ... that will really help me on the other texts I have ... thanks.

Comment: `.*` doesn't match across newlines. Use `[\s\S]*` to match any characters including newlines.

Comment: @Barmar It worked like a charm ... Thank you very much  ... If you can I would also want to ask the following : 1. if instead of Word1, I  have something like this "Word 12:" ... in this case I should escape somehow those characters like space and : ? ... 2 . Is there a possibility to use regex and tell it to extract all text after Word1 and until a newline ?

Comment: 1. You don't need to escape any of those characters. See https://github.com/google/re2/blob/main/doc/syntax.txt for the special characters that need to be escaped.

Comment: `Word1(.*)` Since `.*` stops matching at newline, this extracts everything until newline.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.` doesn't match newlines. To match a multi-line string, use `[\s\S]`. `\s` matches whitespace, `\S` matches non-whitespace, and together in the character set they match anything.

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(B2,"Word1([\s\S]*)Word2")
```